# SQL SERVER : Sequential identity value on Insert

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with this seemingly simple issue.

I have a sql server 2008 table tblCabinet with CabinetID as Primary Key and Identity (Seed=1)
Now i insert into and delete from this table. So now when i enter a new row into tbl insert

```
Insert into tblCabinet values ('F',5,5,5)
```

[image]

It enters a new row with Cabinet ID of 11. I know it has happened because i have deleted the rows in between .
How do i ensure it takes the next available identity, in this case Cabinet ID of 4 by still keeping identity insert ON ? i know i can enter manually by inserting MAX (CabinetID) +1.

Comment: If you care in any way about the *numeric* value of identity columns, you're misusing them. The only sane way to use them is to treat them as opaque blobs that *happen* to fit in numeric columns. You certainly shouldn't ever be displaying them to your users, so their actual values should be irrelevant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Hm..The way i have designed my app now i do have a serial number in the front end which actually map to this identity column. So i do care about the numeric value in identity column. Can you tell me why you would consider that a misuse so that i can change the way i do it now?

Comment: Precisely because the values can jump around. Trying to force them to be sequential will end up imposing ugly hacks and will impose restrictions on insertion (consider two inserts happening at "the same time". One of those inserts has to wait until the other insert (and any other activity within the same transaction) has completed successfully before it can obtain the correct number to use)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the seed permanently like this:

```
declare @max int;  
select @max = max(key) from table;  
dbcc checkident(table,reseed,@max)
```

but really there isn't any nice way to do this I know of.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set Primary Key and Identity off and have to calculate it manually.

your insert query will look like

```
Insert into tblCabinet 
values (Select MAX (CabinetID) +1 FROM tblCabinet ,'F',5,5,5)
```